# background-image is not responding on the header

Tags: html, css, dom

I have tried everything but the background image of the header is not showing up in browsers

in request headers I'm getting this 
Provisional headers are shown
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2825.0 Safari/537.36

```css
//Parallax
 .bird-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(../images/bird-bg.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BlackBird Co.</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-      scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <header class="bird-box">
    <div class="back-bird"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="fore-bird"></div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you share an working fiddle or code snippet? And you added `style.css` inside `<body>` tag, it should be in `<head>` tag

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt (as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) e.g.), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: do you have a url ?

Comment: it could be .JPG instead of .jpg -> i have sometimes the same problem ;)

Comment: yeah I have the right path to the image @ac.freelancer

Comment: I mean a url to see your website. How do you want us to see what's the problem ?We're not magicians.

Comment: still it is not responding  @ac.freelancer

Comment: I see a couple of issues. First off, `<link/>` needs to be moved into `<head>`. Secondly, comments in CSS need to be of the form `/* comment */`.

Comment: I don't think you can use `//` comments in CSS sheets

Comment: even if I put the link in head it is not showing up @AndréDion I think the problem is in the browsers

Comment: It's most definitely not "in the browsers", it's PEBKAC.

Comment: The problem was the comment   thanx everyone

Answer (score 2):

CSS comment syntax is `/* comment here */`. It does not support line comments.

This:

> ```
> //Parallax .bird-box
> ```

… is an invalid selector that doesn't match your element.

Change the comment to be valid CSS.

Comment: Thank the problem was me I merit -2

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong CSS comment syntax! Correct would be `/* comment */`. Unfortunately, there are no one line comments in CSS. You can read more about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments).

```css
/* Parallax */
 .bird-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/300);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BlackBird Co.</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-      scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <header class="bird-box">
    <div class="back-bird"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="fore-bird"></div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```